# "with the case of using" or "in case of using"

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-usage

Should I use **with the case of using** or **in case of using** in the following paragraph?

> We have demonstrated its identification ability and compared its performance **with the case of using** central finite differences from Matlab for the gradient calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*in case of* is a set phrase that's used to describe what to do if some particular event occurs:

> In case of fire, leave via the closest exit.

This is not applicable to your sentence. In your case, *with* is not part of the phrase *with the case of using*, it's the preposition that goes with *compared*, to indicate what is being compared to the the earlier item. It's part of the general pattern

> We compared X with Y.

You could also replace *with* with *to*.